# Creating a PDF in a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I am generating a PDF.  It can potentially take up to 45 seconds, so I decided to make a progress bar.  The progress bar needs to be updated from a thread separate from the UI thread, so I put the "convertNotesToPDF" function in that thread.  The progress bar is updated in the convertNotesToPDF function.  Unfortunately this caused some problems.  About 50% of the time I generate a pdf within the progressbar thread, an unopenable size 0 PDF is generated.  The other 50% of the time it works fine, but that's clearly not going to cut it.  When I put the convert notestopdf outside of the thread, everything works fine.

Here is some code for reference.  First this is the code that works 50% of the time (I took out some unrelated code):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            convertDataToPDF(bmap); 
            convertNotesToPDF();            
            progressBar.dismiss();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        }
    }).start();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

And here is the code when I convertnotestopdf outside of the progressbar thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            convertDataToPDF(bmap); 

            progressBar.dismiss();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        }
    }).start();
            convertNotesToPDF();    
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use an AsyncTask. Its specially designed for this kinda stuff

Comment: Thanks Raghav!  AsyncTask worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are talking about when you refer to a ProgressBarThread.
Rather try to run your PDF processing inside a Thread and inside it's run method update the progressbar like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update your progressbar

                    }
                });
```

So the overall structure is:

```
Thread pdfThread=new Thread(
new Runnable()
{
   public void run()
   {
      convertDataToPDF(bmap); 
      convertNotesToPDF();
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //update your progressbar

                        }
                    });         
   }
}
);
pdfThread.start();
```